# How to use sqlcmd outcome to open as http

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sqlcmd

I have a table in SQL that is essentially a list of websites with a rowID. I would like to pass the result of a query (select website from table where rowid =1 for example) to a .bat file to open the specific website.

When I pass the query I can't clear the ------- line and the (1 row affected) at the end to pick up just the result.

At the moment I have the query saved as sql.bat and am referencing within a further cmd:

```
sql.bat:
sqlcmd -S LOCALHOST-Q "Select 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport' as [Website]"

Follup up cmd:
FOR /F "tokens=*" %a in ('sql.bat') do SET OUTPUT=%a
```

start /max %OUTPUT%

I've tried using skip=2 which does skip the ------ but I can't skip the final row. I want the as start /max https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport but what I'm getting is start /max (1 rows affected)

Comment: So there is a line of text after the one you want to capture? if so, put `set "OUTPUT=" &` in front of your `for /F` loop and instead of `set OUTPUT=%a` write `if not defined OUTPUT set "OUTPUT=%a"`...

Comment: Like so?: set "OUTPUT=" & FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=*" %a in ('sql.bat') do if not defined OUTPUT set "OUTPUT=%a"

This is just returning the ---------------- line

Comment: ...yes, but with an appropriate `skip=` value to process the line of interest as the first one...

Comment: what about `sqlcmd … -Q "set nocount on; select … "` to avoid row counting. also sqlcmd has the `-h-1` switch to avoid display headers.